# After rerender, my input is losing its "class" value (JSF 1.2)

Tags: jsf

I have an inputtext like this:

```
<h:inputText id="cpfCnpjDestino"
    class="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.getStyle()}" tabindex="8"
    required="false" maxlength="18"
    value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.cotacaoDTO.cpfCnpjDestino}"
    disabled="#{boxCotacao.isTipoFreteFob}"/>
```

There's a selecteone that depending on its value, rerenders the inputtext disabling it enabling it.

The thing is, after disabling and enabling it, it's losing its class value (its a mask for the input btw).

Is there a way to keep the class value?

EDIT: Actually, after the rerender, the inputtext is losing its class value, not after disabling and enabling.

EDIT: here are the codes

SelectOneMenu

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="panelTipoFrete">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="tipoFrete" tabindex="1"
    value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.cotacaoDTO.idTipoFrete}"
    label="Selecione" class="selectMiddle" required="false">
    <f:selectItems
    value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.tiposFrete}"></f:selectItems>
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange"
    action="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.renderizarCampoCNPJDestinatario()}"
    reRender="cpfCnpjDestino" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

and the method:

```
public String getStyle(){
        return "cpfCnpjCaracteresDestino";
    }
```

Comment: please post the code for the `selectone(radio/menu)` and the code for `actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.getStyle()`.

Comment: edited with the codes

Comment: I've encounter some of this problems programming with jsf and richfaces. Some things that you should try: 1 - Remove the ajaxsingle attribute and do a test; 2 - try to rerender an external container instead of the exact component like: <somepanel><yourinput/></somepanel> try to rerender the somepanel component and see what happens; 3 - put an breakpoint on the getStyle method and see if it pass there when you change the value of your selectItemns. Do these tests and see what happens.

Comment: I've tested all your options. The getStyle method is being called everytime but it still doesn't work.